# Using ASCII characters in C++ program

Tags: c++

I've been trying to print out `_` <------ this character in a 2D array... But when I

tried compiling the code, it returned some garbage numbers.  I think I'm doing something wrong... can anyone please help me out to solve this problem ?

```
void main (){

    int A[9][9];

    for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
            A[i][j]= '_';//I am doing this part wrong. 
        }

    }

    for (int r=0; r<9; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<9; c++)
            cout << setw(3) << A[r][c];
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You didn't try it with `int` before attempting `int [][]`, did you?

Comment: In addition to `A` being the wrong type, you are not assigning all the elements: `for (int j=0; j<i; j++)` --> `for (int j=0; j<9; j++)`

Answer (score 1):

A is an int array. So cout would try to print an integer. Try `cout << char(A[r][c]);`

Answer (score 1):

The `std::cout::operator<<` operator is overloaded for several data types in order to facilitate (automagically-)formatted output. If you feed it an `int`, then it will print a number. If you give it a `char`, it will try to print it as a character. So either declare your array as an array of `char`, or cast the array member when printing:

```
cout << static_cast<char>(array[i][j]) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>1. Assign the ASCII value to integer array rather than '_'. It will work even without change; but i feel it looks cleaner.</strike>

```
    A[i][j]= 95; // try this instead of '_'
```

1. While printing, cout can print any data type without casting, but since we are looking for character to be printed, try explicit conversion.

   ```
   cout << setw(3) << char(A[r][c]);
   ```
2. Not sure about the compiler you are using, but its a better practice to initialize the array to avoid garbage value tampering with your output

Comment: 1) Why?  How is that an improvement?

Comment: By the time i posted my answer the above two got posted, i personally like answer of @H2CO3 . Use of static_cast is  always preferred and correct.

Comment: But on your first point. The meaning of `A[i][j] = '_';` is clear.  So why would you replace it with `A[i][j] = 95;` which will just make the people reading your code wonder why? (and is theoretically less portable)

Comment: Agree. I didn't thought about portability. +1 for that. Was taught to assign like data types. Edited the answer. Thanks.